# "Replacing" an element matching a predicate in an arbitrarily nested List in Scala

Tags: list, scala, recursion, nested, tail-recursion

I have the following list (just an example - the list can be of an arbitrary depth);

```
val foo = List(1, List(2, List(3, 4)), List(5, List(6, List(7, List(8,9,10)))))
```

I want to traverse the list, and "replace" and element with some value from a predicate.  Something to the effect of

```
map(case 4 => 42 case x => x)
```

and I want it to yield a new List that looks as follows;

```
List(1, List(2, List(3, 42)), List(5, List(6, List(7,List(8,9,10)))))
```

I am trying to do it via recursive function below;

```
def copyListReplace(tree: List[Any], p: Any => Any): List[Any] = {
  tree.map(x =>
    x match {
      case y: List[Any] => copyList(y.tail, p)
      case t => p(t)
    }
  )
}
```

but I am not getting the desired result;

```
scala>println(copyListReplace(foo, (x => x match{ case 4 => 42 case _ => t})))    
List(1, List(List(42)), List(List(7)))
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you can simplify `tree.map(x=> x match {...})` to `tree.map{...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the `y.tail` from your recursive function and just use `y` (map the entire nested list - do not skip the first element).

```
def copyListReplace(tree: List[Any], p: Any => Any): List[Any] = {
  tree.map(x =>
    x match {
      case y: List[Any] => copyListReplace(y, p)
      case t => p(t)
    }
  )
}
```